# Как правильно сделать ViewController ios Swift

Tags: ios, swift, webview

Не могу понять как сделать правильно. Например у меня есть ViewController. В нем сверху UIImageView и два Label. В приложении в большинстве случаев есть Image и два Label. Но иногда бывает так что там надо отобразить видео в WebView между двумя Label, как мне сделать так чтобы если есть видео то между двух Label помещать WebView?

**Платформа iOS 9, Swift 3**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте туда `WebView` и в зависимости от того, надо ли его показывать `webView.hidden = true/false`. И если вы используете `auto layout`, тогда добавьте `IBOutlets` для нужных `constraints` и активируйте или деактивируйте их. `myConstraint.active = true/false`